# Replace NA using a vector of column names

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have a data frame with columns containing `NA`s which I replace using `replace_na`. The problem is these column names can change in the future so I would like to put these column names in a vector and then use the vector in the `replace_na` function. I don't want to change the entire data frame in one go, just specified columns. When I try this as below, the code runs but it doesn't change the data frame. Can anyone suggest any edits to the code?

```
library(tidyverse)
col1<-c(9,NA,25,26,NA,51)
col2<-c(9,5,25,26,NA,51)
col3<-c(NA,3,25,26,NA,51)
col4<-c(9,1,NA,26,NA,51)

data<-data.frame(col1,col2,col3,col4, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

columns<-c(col1,col2)

data<-data%>%
  replace_na(list(columns=0))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`columns` value should be string, you can then use `is.na` as -

```
columns<-c("col1","col2")

data[columns][is.na(data[columns])] <- 0
data

#  col1 col2 col3 col4
#1    9    9   NA    9
#2    0    5    3    1
#3   25   25   25   NA
#4   26   26   26   26
#5    0    0   NA   NA
#6   51   51   51   51
```

Or using `tidyverse` -

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data <- data %>% mutate(across(all_of(columns), replace_na, 0))
```

Answer (score 4):

A `dplyr` option:

```
columns <- c("col1" ,"col2")

dplyr::mutate(data, across(columns, replace_na, 0))
```

Returns:

```
  col1 col2 col3 col4
1    9    9   NA    9
2    0    5    3    1
3   25   25   25   NA
4   26   26   26   26
5    0    0   NA   NA
6   51   51   51   51
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be using `coalesce` inside `map_at`:

- `at` argument in `map_at` can be a character vector of column names that you would like to modify
- We then use `coalesce` function to specify the replacement of `NA`s

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

data %>%
  map_at(c("col1","col2"), ~ coalesce(.x, 0)) %>%
  bind_cols()

# A tibble: 6 x 4
   col1  col2  col3  col4
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     9     9    NA     9
2     0     5     3     1
3    25    25    25    NA
4    26    26    26    26
5     0     0    NA    NA
6    51    51    51    51
```